# Vertx java - sequencing code using compose

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-httpclient

I have a logic where I need to save data in two tables(one-to-many). I have created two methods in my Java and I am trying to using Vertx Future with compose to implement the logic in sequence. But I have got half way and don't understand how to implement the compose when the first future is done. I mean code runs for the first future **anAsyncAction_1(materialToAdd);**, and the record is saved in the DB but now how do I call my second method in the compose

```
public Future<Void> anAsyncAction_2(final SendToCompanyFromSupplier rawmaterialToAdd, Integer id)
{
    //code to get the id from the first future and save data in the table
}
```

Below is my code

```
public Future<Void> adddetails(final Supplier materialToAdd)
    {
        final Promise<Void> added = Promise.promise();
        
        Future<Integer> fut1 = anAsyncAction_1(materialToAdd);
        
        LOG.debug(" future.result()  "+fut1.result());
        
        fut1.compose((outcome) -> {
            LOG.debug(" future.result()  "+outcome);
             
        });

        CompositeFuture.all(fut1, fut2).onComplete(ar ->
        {
            System.out.println("BOTH OPERATION COMPLETED!! 1 " + ar.succeeded());
            try
            {
                System.out.println("BOTH OPERATION COMPLETED!! 2 " + ar.result().list());
                added.complete();
                System.out.println("BOTH OPERATION COMPLETED!!");
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        return added.future();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to compose both the futures, the implementation can be simplified without using `CompositeFuture` or `Promise`.

Sample code:

```java
public Future<Void> adddetails(final Object materialToAdd) {
    Object rawMaterialToAdd = new Object();

    return anAsyncAction_1(materialToAdd).compose(i -> anAsyncAction_2(rawMaterialToAdd, i))
                                         .onComplete(ar -> {
                                           if (ar.succeeded()) {
                                             System.out.println("Both operations completed");
                                           } else {
                                             ar.cause()
                                               .printStackTrace();
                                           }
                                         });


  }

  private Future<Integer> anAsyncAction_1(Object materialToAdd) {
    Promise<Integer> promise = Promise.promise();
    Vertx.currentContext()
         .runOnContext(v -> promise.complete(1)); //Async Call. Replace with async DB call 1
    return promise.future();
  }

  public Future<Void> anAsyncAction_2(final Object rawmaterialToAdd, Integer id) {
    Promise<Void> promise = Promise.promise();
    Vertx.currentContext()
         .runOnContext(v -> {
           System.out.println("Id received:" + id);
           promise.complete();
         }); //Async Call. Replace it with the async DB call 2
    return promise.future();
  }
```

Below is the sequence

1. Async DB call within `anAsyncAction_1` will complete. The id returned will be used to complete the promise. The promise will inturn complete the first future.
2. The future will trigger `anAsyncAction_2` with the id. Async DB call 2 on completion will complete the second future. Post the second future completion the `onComplete` handlers will be executed.